# How to make footer stick to bottom of the page using CSS?

Tags: html, css, footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

I have a webpage that has a footer, but it doesnt stick to the bottom, even when my content is full. I'm using

```
footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0px;
}
```

The footer stays at the bottom of the SCREEN but not the bottom of the PAGE. You can see an example at http://thomaswd.com/2013prototype/index.html. Resize your browser window so that the content's scrollable. The CSS is at http://thomaswd.com/2013prototype/style.css. You can also find another example at http://thomaswd.com/2013prototype/pricing.html. The CSS is at http://thomaswd.com/2013prototype/style2.css. I am using this for the second example: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Use this: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: This is also a good one: `http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/`

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning footer: absolute; bottom:0; that means, it is out side of your container. To solve the problem put you footer inside any container div or section tag.

Answer (score -1):

change `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`
Position absolute takes the element out of the normal flow of content, while fixed does this and sticks it to the page

Comment: but position:fixed will make it stick at the bottom of the screen; I want it to behave like a normal footer.

Comment: then you can't use position:absolute; because then it won't act in the normal content flow. You need to put it after your final content

Comment: never mind, i took the footer styles off and put the footer in the <section>, and it looks like text but works perfectly.